# Twitter API, reply tweets become unavailable

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am trying to post a thread on Twitter through my bot with nodejs. I can successfully post the tweets subsequently by replying to them and create a thread. I use [npm twitter package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter).

I am checking from an external account if tweets are all ok. In the first few seconds it's all good. But when I refresh in less then a minute all tweets above and below a tweet become 'unavailable'. If I log in to the bot account I see tweets are available and connected to each other.

This is how it looks in the website

[image: Overview]

At first tweets are fine. But if I click it a minute later all tweets look like this

[image]

From the bot account, it's all fine

[image]

My reply function is as follows:

```js
function reply(status, prevIdStr, username) {
  return Twitter.post('statuses/update', { status: status, in_reply_to_status_id: prevIdStr, auto_populate_reply_metadata: true });
}
```

I also check if anything changes by comparing Tweet objects before and after. I really can't find a reason why this should be the case. Has anyone an idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why, I ended up opening a new account. It started working

Edit: The reason it worked is that the previous account got marked as spam, because I was testing and excessively tweeting.

Creating a fresh account obviously solves the issue, or contact support to lift you suspension.

Edit 2: With a new account and without posting test tweets I encountered the same issue.... Still investigating.